# How to make payments and refund with flutter

Tags: flutter, payment, razorpay

**My Goal:**

My flutter app needs a way to get money from the user and once a certain level is completed I want to refund the money back to the user.

**My progress:**

Now, I tried [Razopay flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter) but with that, I am not able to refund money unless I go to the dashboard and capture the payments... Razorpay docs suggest using [Orders API](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/) but I don't think Orders API is fit for this simple task. Also, I tried [refunding orders](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/refunds/) using Orders API which I needed to go to the dashboard to capture the payment for making a refund and I can't be capturing every payment as the user base grows.

As I am posting this question I am trying the stripe payment gateway as it can easily be integrated with firebase and another option called [Flutterwave](https://flutterwave.com/us/). I am not sure which one is the best option so I am exploring everything and seeking suggestions.

I just want suggestions on how to make payments and refunds in a flutter app.

*I don't even need a code snippet. Just an idea of any workflow, just some of best practices or pitfalls to look forward is greatly helpful*

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0):

actually I found a way around. You cant refund payment or order without capturing the payment and in order to capture the payment or an order you need to have a server. In my case, I just wrote a simple endpoint with NodeJS and deployed it in Heroku, then whenever I want to capture I call the API. And for refunding, I also opted in server-side for better security.
[NodeJS sample](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/server-integration/nodejs/).

There could be an easier way to do this but this is what I was able to achieve and I tried other options like square, stripe, and all seems to suggest having a server to verify or process the transfer before capturing.

*I am leaving this question open for any other better answer.*